# Error inflating class when custom class is nested class of MainActivity

Tags: android, xml, expandablelistview, classnotfoundexception

I have an expandablelist which contains multiple groups, each of which contains a single child  which is an expandablelist with multiple groups each of which also contain a single child which contains another expandablelist..................and so down the levels.

```
03-17 23:37:30.508    1751-1751/com.multilevellist E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.multilevellist, PID: 1751
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams 
                              cannot be cast to  android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
        at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1826)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1349)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1608)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(
                                      ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.multilevellist.MainActivity">


    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/TopLevelList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#caa551"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"></ExpandableListView>

    <com.multilevellist.MainActivity.NextLevelListView
        android:id="@+id/NextLevelList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#41ca7e"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"></com.multilevellist.MainActivity.NextLevelListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**all_levels_text.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.newShop.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/all_levels_text">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextItem"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.multilevellist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.util.Log.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private final ArrayList<Integer> groupsForEachLevel = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static final ArrayList<Integer> minimumHeights = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private final ArrayList<Object> allLevelViews = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public class ExpandChecker implements OnGroupExpandListener {
        private ExpandableListView listView;
        private int level;

        public ExpandChecker(ExpandableListView listView, int level) {
            w("*****", "onGroupExpand constructor level " + level);
            this.listView = listView;
            this.level = level;
        }

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            w("*****", "onGroupExpand " + level + " " + minimumHeights.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < groupsForEachLevel.get(level); i++) {
                if (i != groupPosition && listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) {
                    listView.collapseGroup(i);
                    for (int ii = level + 1; ii < minimumHeights.size(); ii++) {
                        minimumHeights.set(ii, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        groupsForEachLevel.add(5);
        groupsForEachLevel.add(5);
        groupsForEachLevel.add(5);
        groupsForEachLevel.add(5);
        groupsForEachLevel.add(5);
        groupsForEachLevel.add(5);
        groupsForEachLevel.add(5);

        minimumHeights.ensureCapacity(groupsForEachLevel.size());
        allLevelViews.ensureCapacity(groupsForEachLevel.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < groupsForEachLevel.size(); i++) {
            minimumHeights.add(0);
            allLevelViews.add(null);
        }


        minimumHeights.set(0, 1500);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ExpandableListView topLevelListView = 
                        (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.TopLevelList);
        CustomListAdapter customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(0);

        topLevelListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandChecker(topLevelListView, 0));
        topLevelListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);

        minimumHeights.set(0, topLevelListView.getHeight());
        allLevelViews.set(0, topLevelListView);

    }

    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private NextLevelListView nextLevelListView;
        private final int level;
        private final int lastLevel;
        private int overAllHeight;


        private final int groupsInThisLevel;
        private final int childCount;

        public CustomListAdapter(int level) {
            super();

            this.level = level;
            this.groupsInThisLevel = groupsForEachLevel.get(level);
            this.childCount = 1;
            lastLevel = groupsForEachLevel.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                        w("*****", "getChild");
            return nextLevelListView;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                        w("*****", "getChildId");
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             w("*****", "onChildView  - parent class=" + parent.getClass().getName());


            int nextLevel = this.level + 1;
            Log.w("****", "getChildView level=" + level);

            if (nextLevel <= lastLevel) {
                Log.w("****", "getChildView 1 nextLevel=" + nextLevel);
                CustomListAdapter customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(nextLevel);
                Log.w("****", "getChildView 2 nextLevel=" + nextLevel);

                nextLevelListView = (NextLevelListView)  findViewById(R.id.NextLevelList);
                Log.w("****", "getChildView 3 nextLevel=" + nextLevel);

                nextLevelListView.setLevel(nextLevel);
                nextLevelListView.setGroupIndicator(null);
                nextLevelListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new 
                                    ExpandChecker(nextLevelListView, nextLevel));
                nextLevelListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
                Log.w("****", "getChildView 4 nextLevel=" + nextLevel);


                return nextLevelListView;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            w("*****", "getChildrenCount " + childCount);
            return childCount;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
                        w("*****", "getGroup");

            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
                       w("*****", "getGroupCount " + groupsInThisLevel);
            return this.groupsInThisLevel;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
                        w("*****", "getGroupId " + groupPosition);
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Log.w("****", "getCGroupView  1 level=" + level);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.all_levels_text, null);
            }
            Log.w("****", "getCGroupView  2 level=" + level);

            TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextItem);

            if (level == 0) {
                item.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            } else if (level == groupsForEachLevel.size() - 1) {
                item.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                item.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }

            item.setText(Integer.toString(level) + " -- " + Integer.toString(groupPosition));
            item.setPadding(30 * (level + 1), 0, 0, 0);

            if (level == (groupsForEachLevel.size() - 1)) {
                convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        w("****", "in click listener - future action not yet set ");
                    }
                });
            }
            if (groupPosition == (groupsInThisLevel - 1) 
                        && parent.getHeight() != 0 
                        && minimumHeights.get(level) == 0) {


                for (int i = level; i >= 0; i--) {
                    minimumHeights.set(i, minimumHeights.get(i) + parent.getMeasuredHeight());
                }

                allLevelViews.set(level, parent);
                Log.w("****", "add to array parent l=" +
                        level +
                        " type=" +
                        allLevelViews.get(level).getClass().getName() +
                        " " +
                        minimumHeights.toString() +
                        " " +
                        ((ExpandableListView) allLevelViews.get(level)).getHeight());


            }

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

**NextLevelListView.java**

```
package com.multilevellist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import static android.util.Log.w;

public class NextLevelListView extends ExpandableListView {

    private int level = 0;

    public NextLevelListView(Context context ) {
        super(context );
    }

    public NextLevelListView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
        w("*****", "onMeasure 1 ");


        height = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(1500, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        w("*****", "onMeasure 2 ");
        super.onMeasure(width, height);


        w("*****", "onMeasure 3 ");
    }

    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `<view class="com.multilevellist.MainActivity$NextLevelListView"...`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `com.multilevellist.MainActivity$NextLevelListView` instead of `com.multilevellist.MainActivity.NextLevelListView` in XML. The XML inflation uses Java reflection to find the classes. In Java reflection, `$` distinguishes nested classes from their parents.

Comment: <com.multilevellist.MainActivity$NextLevelListView causes a message "tag start is not closed" to be displayed when I place the cursor on the $ even if I change the close tag to match. I am using android studio and am new at android so it is possible I have missed a setting somewhere.

Comment: @Luksprog and laalto, thanks for your ideas, they lead me to dicover Android Studio doesn't handle the $ sign. I have moved the nested class NextLevelListView out to it's own. This appears to have solved the immediate problem but has highlighted a new one. I have edited the question and included the new code and logcat.